# Matlab: concatenation of 'n' vectors with data from 'n' .csv files within a loop. To show in a structure or table

Tags: arrays, matlab, csv, vector, concatenation

I know there are a lot of posts about concatenation of arrays, but I can't find one that I can use for my case.

I have the following code, that reads a .csv file with mixed data types (using  [this function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23573-csvimport)), and can store the elements of one .csv file into a Vector of dimensions Nx1.

```
basepath = 'Unzipped\Portfolio';
files = dir(fullfile(basepath, '*.csv'));

% Pre-allocate data storage
data = cell(size(files));
N=0;
% Import each file using it's filename
for k = 1:numel(files)

    data{k} = csvimport(fullfile(basepath, files(k).name)); %reads all the data

    [a, b]=size(data{k}); %the size of our data matrix
    Index{k}=a-1;         %Size of one .csv
    N=N+Index{k};         %Size of all .csv

    %for single .csv
    V1s{k}=cell(Index{k}, 1);
    V2s{k}=cell(Index{k}, 1);
    V3s{k}=cell(Index{k}, 1);
    V4s{k}=cell(Index{k}, 1);

    %for all .csv
    V1=cell(N,1);
    V2=cell(N,1);
    V3=cell(N,1);
    V4=cell(N,1);
end

for i = 1:numel(files)
    %Filling out every vector for a single .csv file and showing it up

    [pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(files(i).name);
    V4s{i}(1:Index{i},1)=cellstr(name); %this vector contains only the name of the file repeatedly
    V1s{i}=data{i}(2:end, 15);
    V2s{i}=data{i}(2:end, 14);
    V3s{i}=data{i}(2:end, 9);
    C{i}=[V4s{i} V1s{i} V2s{i} V3s{i}] ;
    Table{i}=array2table(C{i}, 'VariableNames', {'V1s' 'V2s' 'V3s' 'V4s'});

    %For all .csv's
    %This is where my doubts are and I know this one won't produce me any results.
    V4=cat(1,V4s{:});
end
```

My problem comes when I have to make the concatenation of all the vectors one by one. It would be simple if I had, let's say, 3 of 'em.

I could use something like C=[V1; V2; V3]. But I can't find a way to make them all do that.

I was thinking about using counters and start indexing for every i, something like this:

```
V1(a:b,1)=V1s{i}
```

With values a and b being counter. But I don't how to write them.

I want a massive vector Nx1 with all of the V{i} going right after the next set of values.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the {:} operator, it will expand all of the contents of the cell array as input arguments. So if we call [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) with the input data as a cell array, we can do the following to achieve what you want.

```
V1 = cat(1, V1s{:});
```

This is effectively the same as doing

```
V1 = [V1s{1}; V1s{2}; V1s{3}, ..., V1s{n}]
```

Comment: Hi Suever! Thanks for helping me out man. I tried that, and this is what Matlab says: 

Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object.

Comment: Suever, brother, take a look at my approach in my last comment. Worked out just fine. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @AquilesPáez I had tried to make my example more general, I have updated it to be specific to your problem so it will now work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly (to read multiple csv files and store them into a N x 1 vector):

```
C = []; //start with an empty vector
for ... //for each csv file
   M = csvread(filename); //read the csv file into a matrix
   V = reshape(M, [numel(M) 1]); //reshape the matrix into an nx1 vector
   C = vertcat(C, V); //concatenate nx1 vectors into Nx1 vectors
end
```

There are multiple ways to loop through your csv files. Either loop through an array of filenames, or you can obtain all the .csv files in the directory with:

```
files = dir('*.csv');
```

and loop through the csv files like that:

```
for i=1:length(files)
   filename = files(i).name;
   ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Lincoln. There's something very important I forgot to mention and I didn't, and is that the .csv files have mixed data. I believe csvread can't work on those kind of .csv files. I'll edit the original post with that info.

Comment: Instead of `reshape(M, [numel(M) 1])` you can use `reshape(M, [], 1)`. The `[]` can be used once and will be filled automatically to match the right number of elements.

Answer (score -1):

I had to work on an 'alternative' solution. I'm sure there's an easier way. But I'll settle with this one just for now.

I tried this approach: Indexing with counters. For that, you have to define those counters. So, for every different V{i}, you can index those values within a certain range.

To understand this in a better way, you have to add the following part to the last loop in my code above. Obviously, you must say first that counters are equal to zero outside of the loop so it can take an effect.

```
m=m+Index{i};
n=m-Index{i}+1;
V4(n:m,1)=V4s{i};
```

Remember, you have to place it below the commentary line that says

```
% For all .csv's
% This is where my doubts are and I know this one won't produce me any results.
```

And initialize m and n before getting into the loop:

```
m=0;
n=0;
```

You can apply this approach for indexing really large vectors or concatenating several of them.